# Cookies come [Object: null prototype] {}

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, http, cookies

`I want to refresh website. Althoug i can take the cookies when i sent request by postman, i can not take it when i sent request by website '

**Here is my backend. With loginuser i want to set refreshtoken to the cookies. When i sent request with postman it sets the cookies but when i use f5 to refresh website i can not set it**

```
refreshToken: async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    console.log(req.cookies)
    try {
      const rf_token = req.cookies.refreshtoken;
      if (!rf_token)
        return res.status(400).json({ mesage: "Please Login nowwww!" });
      const decoded = <IDecodedToken>(
        jwt.verify(rf_token, `${tokenEnv.refresh}`)
      );
      if (!decoded.id)
        return res.status(400).json({ mesage: "Please Login now!" });

      const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: { userId: decoded.id },
        //TODO
        //select: {password: false}
      });
      if (!user)
        return res.status(404).json({ mesage: "This account does not exist." });

      const access_token = genAccessToken({ id: user.userId });

      res.status(200).json({ access_token, user });
    } catch (error: any) {
      return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
  },
```

```
const loginUser = async (user: IUser, password: string, res: Response) => {
  const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
  if (!isMatch)
  return res.status(400).json({ message: "Password is incorrect" });
  //after login creates a access token
  const access_token = genAccessToken({ id: user.userId });
  // it creates a new access token
  const refresh_token = genRefreshToken({ id: user.userId });
  
  res.cookie("refreshtoken", refresh_token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    path: "/api/refresh_token",
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 1000, //30 days
  });
  

  res.json({
    message: "Login successfully completed!",
    access_token,
    user,
    // user: { ...user, password: "" },
  });
};
```

here is my frontend...

```
export const refreshToken =
  () => async (dispatch) => {
    const refresh = localStorage.getItem("refresh");
    if (refresh !== "todo") return;
    try {
      //const accessToken = access_token
      dispatch({ type: ALERT, payload: { loading: true } });
      const res = await getAPI("refresh_token");
      dispatch({
        type: AUTH, payload:
          res.data
      });
      //localStorage.setItem("logged", res.data.access_token);
      dispatch({ type: ALERT, payload: {} })
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: ALERT, payload: { errors: err?.response?.data.message } });
    }
```

```
onst App = () => {
  const [hamburgerMenu, setHamburgerMenu] = useState(false);
const dispatch = useDispatch()


useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(refreshToken())
}, [dispatch])
```

Postman :

```
Server at listening on port 5000
{
  refreshtoken: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6ImVtcmVrcnQxNjMzOTUiLCJpYXQiOjE2NzA4MDMxOTksImV4cCI6MTY3MzM5NTE5OX0.XkqJhA2FXdTwdX3sWhH-IajIE_xaDysiQ4dYT7FY8Bs'
}
GET /api/refresh_token 200 293.163 ms - 408
```

Frontend by website:

[Object: null prototype] {}
GET /api/refresh_token 400 1.109 ms - 33

Comment: What does `getAPI` do?

Comment: `when i use f5 to refresh website i can not set it`, this is probably because you are setting the cookies onto the response part of the connection. Try setting the cookies to page, e.g., into `document.cookie`

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I:

I have changed `getAPI` from :

```
export const getAPI = async (url,  token) => {
    const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/${url}`, post, {
        headers: { token: token }
    })

    return res
}
```

to:

```
export const getAPI = async (url, token) => {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/${url}`, {
      headers: { token: token },
    });
  
    return res;
  };
```

and i have added  "http://localhost:5000" as proxy  to  package.json

```
"name": "client",
"version": "0.1.0",
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000", // <--
"private": true,
```